# Run checkgmail as a cron job

Tags: cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make cron run a Java GUI application?](https://superuser.com/questions/415424/how-do-i-make-cron-run-a-java-gui-application)

I use checkgmail at work constantly, but this application has a memory leak, and after a week (I never shut down my work machine) or so without an restart it consumes about 1gb of my RAM.

I've thought that I would run a script to restart checkgmail every midnight so I wouldn't have to do it manually. Here's what I've done:

I've created a script in /home/kajman/bin/reset_checkgmail

```
DISPLAY=:0
/usr/bin/killall checkgmail
/usr/bin/checkgmail -no_cookies
```

Then using `crontab -e` I've written:

```
 00 00 * * 0,1,2,3,4,5 /home/kajman/bin/reset_checkgmail
```

I've also tried this:

```
00 00 * * 0,1,2,3,4,5 /usr/bin/checkgmail -no_cookies & > /home/kajman/cron_checkgmail.log
```

Of course during testing, I've changed first two values to match my current time.

The problem is, the `killall` part of script works (I see it killing my checkgmail instance) but then nothing happens. It is the same with the second command.

The script works fine from commandline without cron.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I've found an answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/415424/how-do-i-make-cron-run-a-java-gui-application).

I've had to modify crontab's entry this way:

```
00 00 * * 0,1,2,3,4,5 env DISPLAY=:0 /home/kajman/bin/reset_checkgmail
```

Comment: @slhck The same link that I've given in EDIT section.

Comment: I know. Questions can be closed as duplicates of others, and since in your case the other question solved your problem, we'll close simply it as a duplicate. The above comment was automatically added by the system.

Comment: Well, the solution is exactly the same, so maybe it should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to tell you :)